# Finding value where variable changes

Tags: excel-formula

I am creating an excel worksheet to summarise values in another worksheet. The problem is that I have many different customer ID's and every six month period we receive a summary of their activities on their phone. One column shows whether they have updated to the new OS. It shows a 0 if they haven't and a 1 if they have done it in that 6 month period or prior to that six month period.

I have already tried playing around with `IFERROR` and `INDEX` formulas, but these haven't worked for me.

I really haven't been able to get this to work at all, so I don't have any code to show you. However this is the general format of the data.

In column A you have all the customer ID's and there are multiple entries for each 6 month period. Then in column B you have the date of the 6 month entry, and in Column C a 0 or 1 according to if they haven't or have updated yet respectively.

```
+-------------+--------+----------+
| Customer ID |  Date  | Updated? |
+-------------+--------+----------+
|         001 | Dec-17 |        0 |
|         001 | Jun-17 |        0 |
|         001 | Dec-16 |        0 |
|         001 | Jun-16 |        0 |
|         002 | Dec-17 |        1 |
|         002 | Jun-17 |        1 |
|         002 | Dec-16 |        0 |
|         003 | Dec-17 |        1 |
|         003 | Jun-17 |        1 |
|         003 | Dec-16 |        1 |
|         003 | Jun-16 |        0 |
|         003 | Dec-15 |        0 |
+-------------+--------+----------+
```

The output should be in a separate tab which only has the unique Customer IDs and look like this:

```
+-------------+--------------+
| Customer ID | Date Updated |
+-------------+--------------+
|         001 | 0            |
|         002 | Jun-17       |
|         003 | Dec-16       |
+-------------+--------------+
```

I think it will require array formulas, but don't really know how these work.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This is extremely hard to work with. Please post your data as a table, with the data in columns. Or share a file in one of the ad-free file sharing services.

Comment: Why Dec-16 for 003?? Their latest date is Dec-17. What is your logic to arrive at these results?

Comment: It is the first date that they updated their phone, so even though 003 has had they're phone updated in the data received on Dec-17, it was first updated in the data received Dec-16. This is how I arrive at the results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that the dates are real dates, not text:

If you have Office 365 you can use Minifs

```
=MINIFS(Table1[month],Table1[id],F5,Table1[value],1)
```

If you don't have that function, you can use this array formula:

```
=MIN(IF((Table1[id]=F5)*(Table1[value]=1),Table1[month]))
```

Remember to confirm with Ctrl+Shift+Enter.

Format the result with custom format `mmm-yy;;0` which shows 0 for 0 values, not dates.

Adjust the formulas accordingly, if you want to place them on a different sheet.

[image]

Edit after comment: The formulas I posted use structured referencing to the Excel Table. If your data is not in a Table Object or you don't want to use structured references, you can use regular references, of course.

```
=MINIFS($C$5:$C$16,$B$5:$B$16,F5,$D$5:$D$16,1)
```

or

```
=MIN(IF(($B$5:$B$16=F5)*($D$5:$D$16=1),$C$5:$C$16))
```

Comment: How are you able to reference the cells as Table1?? Is it possible to use VLOOKUP instead? If so, how?

Comment: The referencing to the table happens automatically when the data is in an Excel table and the Excel options are set to use structured references. No, VLookup is not suitable. I'll add the formula with cell references, if you find that easier.